# Vim: Is there a way to index a custom maker in tagbar ctags?

Tags: vim, ctags, divider

I am using the tagbar plugin in VIM to create a toggleable "contents page" of ctags to help me navigate class methods, properties and functions etc.

Often when coding, I like to use dividers to help break up large classes (which should not be subclassed). (See below for code example). Is there any way to make these appear in the ctags list?

Please do not comment on the semantics of dividing up a class in this way - the example below is arbitrary!

```
class ToBeIndexed
{

    ####################################
    attributes
    ####################################

    public $casper;
    public $slimer;
    public $tomJoad;

    ####################################
    methods
    ####################################

    #=====================
    # magic methods
    #=====================

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    #=====================
    # create methods
    #=====================

    function createFoo()
    {

    }

    function createBar()
    {

    }

    #=====================
    # update methods
    #=====================

    function updateBaz()
    {

    }
}
```

Edit: The format of the dividers within the code doesnt matter. I wonder if theres a way to make the divider indexed if it appeared as something like this:

```
#####..regexfindme..####################################
# methods
########################################################
```